# Only show columns that are filled from external JSON in ExtJS 3.x

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs3

I am parsing an external JSON source in ExtJS and want to display the data in a ExtJS grid. 
Which works already perfectly.

There is a maximum set of fields that is predicitable, but in most cases some of the fields are empty/not in the JSON. If a field is not filled at all, it should not be hidden.

Is there a functionality to hide this dynamically in ExtJS 3.x?

My code so far:

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url     : '/data/all.json',
    storeId : 'mainStore',
    fields  : ['name', 'company', 'country']
});
store.load()


var columns = [];
    var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
        {header: 'Name', sortable: true, dataIndex: 'name', filterable: true, hidden: false, filter: {type: 'string'}},
        {header: 'Company', sortable: true, dataIndex: 'company', filterable: true, hidden: false, filter: {type: 'string'}},
        {header: 'Country', sortable: true, dataIndex: 'country', filterable: true, hidden: false, filter: {type: 'string'}},

    ]);
```

My JSON could look like:

This should display all fields.

```
[ {"name": "Jon Doe", "company": "ACME Inc.", "country": "Mexico"},
{"name" : "Jane Doe", "company" : "ACME Ltd", "country" : "USA"}]
```

This should only show name and company.

```
[ {"name": "Jon Doe", "company": "ACME Inc."},
{"name" : "Jane Doe", "company" : "ACME Ltd"}]
```

This should again show all fields.

```
[ {"name": "Jon Doe", "company": "ACME Inc."},
{"name" : "Jane Doe", "company" : "ACME Ltd", "country" : "USA"}]
```

Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that evaluates the data and return a boolean.

```
var showOrHideColumns = function(columnName) {
    var records = store.getRange(),
        hidden = false;

    Ext.each(records, function(itm, idx) {
        if (!itm.get(columnName)) {
            hidden = true;
            break;
        }
    });

    return hidden;
};
```

And use the above function in your headers. You may want to check the scope of the method in your code.

```
{ header: 'Name', hidden: showOrHideColumns }
```

Note: The above code is not tested.